# I can`t Push the branch to <remote> , along with necessary commits and objects

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

Iam getting a result like this every time I try to push.
i tried force push,rebase,init nothing worked.

```
nayananga@nayananga-Aspire-E5-575G:/opt/lampp/htdocs/registration$ git push 'https://nayanangamuhandiram@bitbucket.org/group4suoj2016/version-1.0.git' 'nayananga`s_branch'
Password for 'https://nayanangamuhandiram@bitbucket.org': 
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.02 KiB | 1.02 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: One of your commit messages is missing a valid issue key:
remote: 
remote:   3517c56: CompleteUserRegistrationUsingPhpAndMysqlDatabase
remote: 
remote: For more information, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE.
remote: 
To https://bitbucket.org/group4suoj2016/version-1.0.git
 ! [remote rejected] nayananga`s_branch -> nayananga`s_branch (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://nayanangamuhandiram@bitbucket.org/group4suoj2016/version-1.0.git'
```

any help?

```
nayananga@nayananga-Aspire-E5-575G:/opt/lampp/htdocs/registration$ git push origin 'nayananga`s_branch'
Password for 'https://nayanangamuhandiram@bitbucket.org': 
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.02 KiB | 1.02 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: One of your commit messages is missing a valid issue key:
remote: 
remote:   3517c56: CompleteUserRegistrationUsingPhpAndMysqlDatabase
remote: 
remote: For more information, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE.
remote: 
To https://bitbucket.org/group4suoj2016/version-1.0.git
 ! [remote rejected] nayananga`s_branch -> nayananga`s_branch (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://nayanangamuhandiram@bitbucket.org/group4suoj2016/version-1.0.git'
```

@tim

```
nayananga@nayananga-Aspire-E5-575G:/opt/lampp/htdocs/registration$ git push origin master
Password for 'https://nayanangamuhandiram@bitbucket.org': 
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.02 KiB | 1.02 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: One of your commit messages is missing a valid issue key:
remote: 
remote:   6cfab63: CompleteUserRegistrationUsingPhpAndMysqlDatabase
remote: 
remote: For more information, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE.
remote: 
To https://bitbucket.org/group4suoj2016/version-1.0.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://nayanangamuhandiram@bitbucket.org/group4suoj2016/version-1.0.git'
```

@R

Comment: Why aren't you doing something like `git push origin nayananga`s_branch` ?  Check the documentation for how to do a `git push`.

Comment: As an aside, was a backtick in a branch name *necessary*? Sounds like asking for trouble. You even broke Tim's comment ;-)

Comment: @tim I updated the question with that try, still same

Comment: @RomainVALERI I updated the question with that try, still same

Comment: I removed all branching permissions in bitbucket and I`m the administer of the repo if that matters

Comment: Looks like you have a pre-commit hook that is rejecting your commit.  On a normal git server, you would just need to change or delete the file `hooks/pre-commit`.  Now you just need to find the bitbucket equivalent of doing that.

Comment: Thanks to your pointing I able to find the solution to the problem. I`ll answer down here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on this I was able to find the solution.I'll post the solution here

> We are receiving reports that some customers are receiving "pre-receive hook declined" errors when attempting to push. We are investigating. 
>   If you are experiencing this issue, there is a workaround. As a repository admin, you can go to the repository settings -> "Links" section. Then disable "Require issue keys in commit messages".
>   Posted about 2 months ago. Jul 09, 2018 - 10:52 UTC 
>   https://status.bitbucket.org/incidents/j71s01py6mb6

hope it will help others

Comment: This was the solution to my problem. My team uses BitBucket, so to solve this you'd go to repository settings -> Merge checks -> Disable.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I have once committed my code without "Issue Key" in the message and after getting that issue, I committed with "Issue Key" again but still I was getting the same error message.

So the solution is

First Check all your commit logs by the following the command:

```
git log
```

By the above command, you will get a list of commit logs. From the list, you can remove your most recent commit by following the command (**Warning**: Do not remove your commit without taking backup if you are not sure, you might lose your code)

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

It removed my commit which was having no "Issue Key" attached to it. Then I commit again and pushed my code like below:

```
git add .
git commit -m"XXXXX-504: my message"
git push
```

And it worked for me.

---

To prove it, start a new branch, change a file and **check-in with the message containing only the** (JIRA, AzureDevOps, RALLY, etc) **ticket ID**, eg: `CP-54321`

Comment: This should be accepted as correct answer. Removing repository settings is just a workaround.

Comment: this is the proper answer, the XXXXX-504 should be a issue created in JIRA related with your commit

Answer (score 4):

Need to create a link between GIT commit <-> JIRA ticket, so include JIRA ticket ID into the commit message.
Example: If JIRA Ticket ID is “PD-0707“, you commit message should like as below.

git commit -m "PD-0707 Resolving GIT key issue"

Answer (score 1):

If youre working with Bitbuckets, and pipelines, and youve altered the repository settings...

Make sure you uncheck Require issue keys in commit messages if you go around fooling with things like I did before realizing what it was going to do....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is often encountered when you try to push to a working jira project branch that is tied to an issue-key(e.g T-20, M-5, Z-47).
Jira requires you to state the issue key in the comment of your commit message

```
git commit -m "M-5 added a README file to the repo"
```

I personally think the error could be worded correctly, but that's what the error states in essence.